# iOS Kiwi parameterized test like NUnit

Tags: ios, unit-testing, tdd, kiwi

Is there a way to parameterize test with Kiwi ?

If you are familiar with NUnit, it has a feature of running a test with parameters
( see http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCase&r=2.5 ).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a macro that generates the if(..., ^{ });
This will show the correct error message if the test failed, but you can not debug :( .

Here is an example of how it looks like:

```
let(_userModel, ^id{
    return [[MyUserModel alloc] init];
});

#define email_should_be_valid(email) \
    it(@ #email " should be valid", ^{\
        [_userModel setEmail:email];\
        [[theValue([_userModel validate:nil]) should] beTrue];\
    });

email_should_be_valid(@"example@dd.m")
email_should_be_valid(@"example.example@dd.x")
email_should_be_valid(@"example@dd.com")

#undef email_should_be_valid
```

I will not mark this answer as correct, hope somebody comes with a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

There's one way that works for me.

Basically,

1. *Define your own block in test file that gets your parameter(s)*

   > ```
   > typedef void(^TestCount)(INT count);
   > ```
2. *Create the block with corresponding tests*

   > ```
   > TestCount testCount = ^(INT count){
   >    [[someObject shouldNot] beNil];
   >    [[someObject should] have:count] rows];
   > };
   > ```
3. *Execute parametrized block wherever you need it, i usually do this within it's block*

   ```
   context(@"when adding object", ^{

       beforeAll(^{
           [someObject addObject:anotherObject];
       });


       it(@"it should have 1 object", ^{
           testCount(1);
       });
   });
   ```

I hope this helps